# How do I get programmatic error codes from Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm using the Cognito Javscript SDK, and I've created a form where a user can register an account. If, for whatever reason, server-side validation fails, the response looks like this:

```
{
  "__type":"InvalidParameterException",
  "message":"4 validation errors detected: Value at 'password' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 6; Value at 'password' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\S]+; Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1; Value at 'username' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{S}\\p{N}\\p{P}]+"
}
```

The problem with this response is that I can't provide good user feedback because I'd have to parse the response to determine which fields need to be fixed. Is there a way to get the errors back in a format that is better for working with programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this at the moment, is to programmatically grab the values by cutting out the substrings after 'value at'.

I haven't got an example of any library that might help in doing this but this is good feedback though.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Do you know if there's a github issue to track this? If not I'll submit one.

Comment: I haven't seen one, but you should definitely submit one! AWS engineers keep an eye on them closely! I'll submit this feedback too!

Comment: Here ya go! https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/388

Comment: Thanks! Can't makes any guarantees as to if/when this will be implemented, but can make sure the team are aware of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is stumbling on this ages later, the answer is to use response.code:

```
        this.cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
            onSuccess: (data) => {

            },
            onFailure: (data) => {
                console.log(data) 
                /*
                {
                   "__type":"InvalidParameterException",
                   "message":"4 validation errors etc"
                }
                */
                console.log(data.code)
                /*
                   "InvalidParameterException"
                */
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first json stringify and then json parse the object to get values.

Try following sample code -

```html
var errorObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(errorObj.statusCode);
```